# please tell me how can i access value of gridview's cell in javascript

Tags: asp.net, javascript, gridview, drop-down-menu

i have a gridview witch contain 4 databound columns and 2 templated column. in one of template column i placed a dropdownlist(witch contain number of items). and 2nd column of gridview contains prices. so in last column i want that when i select value in dropdownlist that value should multiply with 2nd column's value of datagrid and place result in last column of gridview using java script.

please tell me what to do..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the row and column cell data using javascript. Here is a nice article on

[Traversing an HTML table with JavaScript and DOM Interfaces](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/traversing_an_html_table_with_javascript_and_dom_interfaces)

Also take a look at [table.rows](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/table.rows)

**Sample Code**

HTML

```
<table>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    100
                </td>
                <td>
                    <select id="sel1" onchange="GetRowInd(this);">
                        <option value="1">1</option>
                        <option value="2">2</option>
                        <option value="3">3</option>
                    </select>
                </td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    100
                </td>
                <td>
                    <select id="sel2" onchange="GetRowInd(this);">
                        <option value="1">1</option>
                        <option value="2">2</option>
                        <option value="3">3</option>
                    </select>
                </td>
                <td>

                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
```

javascript

```
function GetRowInd(selectbox)
    {
        var parentTr = selectbox.parentNode.parentNode;
        var secondCellVal = parseInt ( parentTr.cells[0].innerText , 10 );
        var comboVal = parseInt ( selectbox.value , 10 );

        parentTr.cells[2].innerText = secondCellVal * comboVal;
    }
```

You have to use textContent instead of innerText to work in FF.

***jQuery solution***

Remove the onchange event from the combo box and use the following function

```
$(function() {
            $(".selectbox").change ( function() {
                var comboVal = $(this).val();
                var parentTr = $(this).parents('tr');  
                var tdElem = parentTr.children('td');             
                var secondCellVal = tdElem.eq('0').text();

                tdElem.eq('2').text ( comboVal * secondCellVal );
            });
        });
```

Comment: its good thing to learn but not supported to solution. i want that when ever i select a value in dropdownlist (in gridview) it calls a function of javascript and i should be able to retrive that value of second field of that same row and place result in last column of same row

Comment: can u please tell me more how can i do grand total of all that...?

Answer (score 1):

You should be using `ClientID` property of the serverside controls and `document.getElementById` method to access your controls using javascript.

You may find [this](http://www.onedotnetway.com/working-with-client-id-in-asp-net-4/) article helpful for generating neat ClientIDs.
[This](http://forums.asp.net/t/1249047.aspx) forum discussion may also show you the right way out.

**Upd.:**
Sample html:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>cellValue</td>
        <td><span id="comboId">combo</span></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Sample javasricpt:

```
// alerts "cellValue"
alert(document.getElementById("comboId").parentNode.parentNode.cells[0].innerHTML);
```

Comment: i think you all are not getting me.. i know ClientIDs ..... ok.i have written this javascript code:

        function ShowTotalPrices(dropDown) {

        var selectedStatus = dropDown.value; //here i am getting value of my dropdownlist
var price= //tell me what should i write here to retrive value of same row in witch this dropdownlist exists who called this function
       

        }

Comment: @Dot Net Developer Updated the answer to meet your request.